# How to let users download data from Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver

I'm looking for a way to let user download data made visible to him from Geoserver. I was thinking about using WFS for this purpose, but I don't know how to make it authenticated/secured? Do I have any other option?

Comment: Please go through following link may be helpful for you http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html#wfs-outputformat-shapezip ,http://www.mail-archive.com/geoserver-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01656.html

Comment: Is it possible to use REST for downloading data? I need the download to be programatically accessible with thte script. Also it would be great to have it as KML file. Doing this is not an issue, but I'm struggling with securing data that should not be visible to the user.

Comment: @zimmi It's not REST, it's a simple HTTP GET request...to get a kml file you have to perform a WMS request, see [the docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/outputformats.html)